# Train LSTM model on keras with several multivariate time series

Tags: keras, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

I have a time series dataset of customer behavior. For each month, I have one row per customer which includes a set of features(for example, the amount of spending, number of visits, etc.) and a target value(a binary value; does the customer buy product "A" or not?).

My problem is: I want to train an LSTM model to predict the target value for the next month(does the customer buy product "A" next month?). Since I have multiple time series(one per customer), I have more than one sample per timestamp(for example, for January 2010, I have more than 1000 samples, and so on). How do I train the model? Do I go epoch by epoch and for each epoch, fit the model one by one on all customers? Is there another side to this I'm missing?

```
Dataset features:
Number of customers: 1500;
Length of time series: 120;
Number of features per customer: 80(before adding time-shifted features);
```